# Jquery condition is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

I am working on fixing a website which is coded by someone else. Codes are really messy so I am afraid I can't post it all here but I believe I provided enough information for you to see what could be wrong. Because at this point I am lost.

**1. We get min and max limits**

```
parent_id = '<?php echo $parent_id; ?>';
api = '<?php echo $api; ?>';
    $.getJSON('getlimits.php', {'id': ""+parent_id+"", 'api': ""+api+""}, function(data) {
        // Loop and assign Json (returned value) to our limit variables
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            min_limit = key;
            max_limit = val;
        });
    });
```

**getlimits.php OutPut:**

```
{"10":"15000"}
```

**2. We check the limits**

```
amount = $('#quantity', this).val();

console.log(amount + ' - Max : ' + max_limit + ' Min : ' + min_limit);

if ( amount < min_limit) {
    displayError("You can't order less than " + min_limit + " units",2000);
    return false;
}
else if ( amount > max_limit ) {
    displayError("You can't order more than " + max_limit + " units.",2000);
    return false;
}
```

**Logged Results;**

```
800 - Max : 15000 Min : 10
```

I typed 800 units. It shouldn't give any error but I am getting following error;

**You can't order more than 15000 units.**

I am truly lost. Log shows correct values, getlimits.php returns correct values but if & else if conditions are not working.

I will be glad if anyone could help me out with this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that every value is an int ? try to `parseInt` every value before the conditions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`amount` is not an integer when you grab it through `.val()`.

So adjust this line:

```
amount = $('#quantity', this).val();
```

to

```
amount = parseInt($('#quantity', this).val());
```

As pointed out by Dennis, you will have to `parseInt` the values you are grabbing from the JSON as well. (`min_limit` and `max_limit`).

As Dennis also pointed out, you should add `10` as a second parameter to `parseInt` to make sure it parses as a decimal number.

So:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    min_limit = parseInt(key,10);
    max_limit = parseInt(val,10);
});

amount = parseInt($('#quantity', this).val(),10);
```

Comment: Indeed. @Pixeler, the fundamental reason for what you're seeing is that the string "800" is not between the strings "10" and "15000" in *alphabetical* order, which is what you're testing for.

Comment: JSON keys are strings, so that is necessary as well.  It also helps to provide 10 as a second parameter to parseInt() so it is guaranteed to parse as a decimal number (not octal, hex etc...)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are comparing a string to string:

```
"800" > "15000" === true
```

You need to convert at least one (preferably both) to a number with parseInt:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    min_limit = parseInt(key);
    max_limit = parseInt(val);
});

amount = parseInt($('#quantity', this).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `parseInt(number, 10)` to get a numeric variable.  It looks like you are comparing strings which will give you different results from comparing numbers.  The second parameter (10) is the radix, which will make sure you get a decimal value.

You need to do this for min_limit and max_limit, as well as the `.val()` call, which will always return a string.